# Azure API Management: Doing a global policy for set-backend-service results in scope error

Tags: azure-api-management, policies

So globally on my API service, I always wish to set the backend service URL based on certain calling regions.

According to this [MSDN library article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7406a8ce-5f9c-4fae-9b0f-e574befb2ee9?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#SetBackendService), using the set-backend-service policy sounds perfect for this, and it's a global policy according to its policy scope at the bottom.

However, even posting their exact example...

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2013-05")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/8.2/" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2014-03")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/9.1/" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
```

....results in an error:

> "Error in element 'set-backend-service' on line 0, column 0: Policy is
>   not allowed in the specified scope"

I can't figure out how to make it any simpler of a situation to troubleshoot.  I even removed the conditional statement and just left the policy alone and it still shows the scope error.

I know this global scope works okay, since I was able to put in an xml-to-json policy as a temporary test and save successfully.

I would figure someone ran into this issue already, as this must be a common use case for this policy.  Otherwise, I think the MSDN article is out of date, unless anyone here can see any issues.

Here's my policy scope for global:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the quotes to single quotes where "version" is. I just ran the following no problem:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault('version') == '2013-05')">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/8.2/" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault('version') == '2014-03')">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/9.1/" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin, but no luck.  I'm getting a new error with this version:  "Too many characters in character literal".  Changing your single quotes back into double quotes removes that error and goes back to my original error.

Also, I know this wouldn't work on a global policy.  <base /> wouldn't be allowed on a global policy, as there isn't anything more base than global :)  Are you trying it there?

Comment: @RudyScoggins that is the behavior i see as well. without copying code if you see in global policy scope if we place the cursor within <inbound> and </inbound> the set backend service policy statement is grayed out contrary to what is listed in the document. i hope some one from Azure APIM team takes a note of the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your expression. The method `GetValueOrDefault` requires a second parameter as default value.

This is working for me:

```xml
<when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version", "") == "1")">
                ...
            </when>
```